# What faction quests are the point of no return?

Tags: fallout-4

I am aware that I seem to be approaching the end of the game, if you can't tell you are yet then do not read this as it may include some spoilers of future quests, if this doesn't affect you then continue.

I am trying to get the Brotherhood of Steel ending of the game, currently up to the quest "Blind Betrayal", however trying to clear up as many other faction quests as possible before going too far into the Brotherhood of Steel quest line.

I'm currently at the Institute quest "The Battle of Bunker Hill", it has optional objectives such as inform the Railroad/Brotherhood of Steel or simply continue on behalf of the institute.

I have read somewhere that if I were to simply following the Institute here then it will result in being sided with them.

I'd ultimately like to free the synths from the bunker (Railroad) but side with the Brotherhood of Steel overall, however when I return to the Railroad I am given the quest "Underground undercover", will proceeding with this quest make the Brotherhood of Steel dislike me/prevent me getting the Brotherhood of Steel ending?

If the above is true, it seems I am going to have to kill the synths in the bunker which I was trying to avoid as I have been trying to give synths better lives.

Comment: If I may ask, which RR quest is the final quest I am able to complete if I am trying to side with the BOS?

Comment: My question slightly differs. I asked what is the point of no return, other post is asking where the choices for factions begin.

Comment: So I just realized when i go to Desdemona to begin the  "Underground undercover" quest of installing the holotape within the institute, there is a dialogue "Side with railroad" and "Side with brotherhood", however I am not given any message alerting me? Is this the point of no return or am I able to lie here and say railroad then actually complete the BOS path after this quest is complete?